# Write XML using saxon as a library

Tags: java, xml, saxon

I can write this XML using Java DOM:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"
         xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
         xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">
      <cac:Employee id="1">
        <cbc:name>Pankaj</cbc:name>
        <cbc:age>29</cbc:age>
        <cbc:role>Java Developer</cbc:role>
        <cbc:gender>Male</cbc:gender>
      </cac:Employee>
      <cac:Employee id="2">
        <cbc:name>Lisa</cbc:name>
        <cbc:age>35</cbc:age>
        <cbc:role>Manager</cbc:role>
        <cbc:gender>Female</cbc:gender>
      </cac:Employee>
    </Invoice>
```

But, I'm wondering if I can write this XML using the [Saxon](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/package-summary.html) Library. Saxon library is a powerful library to do things like XPath evaluation, fast reading, XSLT transformation, and so on, but I didn't found any example of how to write and XML with that library.
Is it possible? If were possible, could you give me any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "write"? Store it in a File? Transform a Java Object into XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's actually a range of mechanisms, some quite well established and others relatively new.

You can construct a `Serializer` using `Processor.newSerializer()`, and then get either a SAX `ContentHandler` (with `Serializer.getContentHandler`) or a StAX `XmlStreamWriter` (with `Serializer.getXMLStreamWriter`) enabling you to write to the serializer an event at a time. These mechanisms have the advantage that the API is standard, but I don't find either of them very user-friendly.

More recently I introduced the Push API, which has more of a "fluent API" feel to it, in that when you start an element node, it returns a handle that you can use for writing the children and attributes of the element.

Also new, and a little experimental, is the Sapling tree. This constructs a lightweight immutable tree in memory, which can then be written out to a Serializer when you're finished.

For both these newer APIs, the main documentation is the Javadoc.